# Complex Measures: Absolute Continuity

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

*Note: This is a lemma for: [Spectral Measures: Riemann-Lebesgue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/983081/79762)*

Given a positive measure:
$$\lambda:\mathcal{A}\to[0,\infty]$$

Consider a complex measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}$$

> How to prove the equivalence?
>   $$\mu\ll\lambda\iff|\mu|\ll\lambda$$
>   *(This can be quite helpful in some situations!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint: There are actually a few proofs; here's one.*

Positive measures preserve null sets:
$$\lambda(N)=0:\quad\lambda(E)=0\quad(E\subseteq N)\implies\mu(E)=0\quad(E\subseteq N)$$
So the Radon-Nikodym must vanish here:
$$E\subseteq N\quad0=\mu(E)=\int_E u\mathrm{d}|\mu|\implies u1_N=0\mod{|\mu|}$$
That in turn gives absolute continuity:
$$|\mu|(N)=\int_N|u|\mathrm{d}|\mu|=0$$